# Why are labels and looks different between print layout and map canvas at same scale?

Tags: qgis-3, mac

I know that some of my items uses map unit as size unit, others mm and labels points. But the map canvas where I do all my changes should still look exactly the same in print layout if I'm using the same map scale. Am I overlooking something?

I'm running QGIS 3.4.4 on macOS 10.14.3

[image: Print layout, scale 1:50k]

[image: Map canvas, scale 1:50k]

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the scale of the map canvas refers to the relationship between the units of the map and the dimension of the screen on which it is represented. The scale of the map item in the layout, on the other hand, refers to the relationship between the map units and the dimension of the paper in which it is represented. Therefore, I think that both representations do not have to be congruent for those styles defined in _mm_ and in _pixels_.

Comment: I can't see that behaviour with _map units_ nor _mm_ nor _points_, are you sure that the styles are not setted to _pixels_? Project CRS and Map Item CRS are the same? Are you using a projected or geographic CRS?

Comment: the DPI is different so the scale is different

Comment: Both @GabrielDeLuca and Ian Turton got me thinking about what is actually best for my project. DPI will be different for the 2 situations where I used mm and points as units. I'll redefine and try map units for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution will be different and DPI, PPI won't match between my screen and print. So using units like "mm" and "points" should give the difference I had in my question.

SOLUTION: In my case, redefining everything in map units worked fine and now I can do all the fine adjustments on the map canvas and expect the same outcome when exporting or printing.